# Encode TextArea for GET request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to pass the contents of a textarea as the source attribute of an image tag and capture all input including line breaks etc.

It looks like the only way to do this is to base 64 encode it and then urlEncode the result. (I can then unencode it all server side.)

1. Is that correct?
2. Is there a preferred base 64 library for javascript? must be cross browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It looks like the only way to do this is to base 64 encode it and then urlEncode the result. (I can then unencode it all server side.)

You only need to base64 encode binary data - which a textarea won't contain.

Just use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Ok this works fine. My hangup was that I am forming a url that is being passed to an ASP.NET MVC controller which couldn't handle the special characters in the routing engine. Solution is to add the encoded value as a query string parameter instead of a routing component: url.../id/?t=encodedtext instead of url../id/encodedtext/

Answer (score 0):

urlEncode should be enough (no need for base64 as you could express line breaks as (e.g.) `%0D%0A` as well) but whatever you're building sounds quite vulnerable to cross site scripting exploits.